# Windows file attribute change monitor

Tags: windows, monitoring, files

I need a tool that monitors file changes in a specific folder even at attribute level. Anybody can recommend one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tool found so far is 'Watch 4 Folder', it allows to specify the folder to be monitored and all the status changes on the included files.

Answer (score 1):

We are using [iwatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html) for this task, which is also based on the `inotify` kernel features. Of course this only works on Linux, since you did not mention a specific operating system.

Watching for attribute changes would look like this:

```
iwatch -c script-to-run.sh -e attrib,modify /directory/to/watch
```

Iwatch can also send emails and has a [good documentation](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) for its features and usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to want to install [inotify-tools](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/). You can watch a file and get notified with the contents change, attributes are touched, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On windows there is this shareware: http://www.datamystic.com/filewatcher.html